# Android broadcast receiver get registered multiple times when activity minimise and maximise

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Hi I am working with android.I am looking to update ui from service data. So that I get data from service via broadcast receiver succesfully and I updated listview when value changes.My problem is that during activity running, if i minimise the activity and then maximise, the another receiver is get registered and which will repeats my listview data.How can I set only one receiver when after maximise ? here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ListView l1;
       ArrayList<String> t1=new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> d1=new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<Integer> i1=new ArrayList<Integer>();


    MyReceiver myReceiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(t1,d1,i1));


    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          //Register BroadcastReceiver
          //to receive event from our service



          myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
          IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
          intentFilter.addAction(MyService.MY_ACTION);
          registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);

          //Start our own service
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                  com.example.androidservice.MyService.class);
          startService(intent);
          super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

     unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
     stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
     super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

     //unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
     stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
     super.onPause();
    }

    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

      String datapassed1 = arg1.getStringExtra("DATAPASSED1");
      String datapassed2 = arg1.getStringExtra("DATAPASSED2");

      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "Triggered by Service!\n"
        + "Data passed: " + String.valueOf(datapassed1),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      t1.add(datapassed1);
      d1.add(datapassed2);

      for(int i=0;i<t1.size();i++)
      {

          i1.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

      }





      l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(t1,d1,i1));

     }

    }

    class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       ArrayList<String> Title, Detail;
        ArrayList<Integer> imge;

        dataListAdapter() {
            Title = null;
            Detail = null;
            imge=null;
        }

        public dataListAdapter(ArrayList text, ArrayList text1,ArrayList text3) {


            notifyDataSetChanged();

            Title = text;
            Detail = text1;
            imge = text3;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Title.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row;
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
            TextView title, detail;
            ImageView i1;
            title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            detail = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            i1=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img);
            title.setText(Title.get(position));
            detail.setText(Detail.get(position));
            i1.setImageResource(imge.get(position));

            return (row);
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the broadcast receiver and start the service in onCreate(), and
unRegister the receiver and stop the service in onDestroy().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    //l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(t1,d1,i1));
    //Register BroadcastReceiver
      //to receive event from our service
      myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
      IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
      intentFilter.addAction(MyService.MY_ACTION);
      registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);

      //Start our own service
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
              com.example.androidservice.MyService.class);
      startService(intent);


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

 unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
 stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));
 super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register your `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume` and unregister it in `onPause`. After that, you don't need to register/unregister it in any of the other activity's lifecycle methods.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(MyService.MY_ACTION));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There should be something missing here (Perhaps your manifest). It seemed correct to me how to handle your receivers (you don't necesarily to use onPause-onResume to register/unregister).

Please make sure you don't also register the receiver @ the manifest file as well.